# Android Studio Integrating Google Endpoints Generated libraries

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to include a generated client library to query Google Cloud Endpoints to my Android Studio process.

I have included the depedencies libs in `/libs` folder of the project.

I have unarchived the source of the .jar containing the specific code for the API I am using. And I have copy-pasted it to my source folder.

[image: Project Tree]

I am encountering compilation error in the generated API files when I try to compile my project.

Here is my builg.gradle file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
   compileSdkVersion 17
   buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 8
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs/google_end_points/", includes: ['*.jar'])
}
```

I am getting several compilation error like this (Note `com.google.api.services.positivityapi` is the generated API from Google Cloud Endpoints):

```
Gradle: com.google.api.services.positivityapi.Positivityapi.Appreciation.List is already defined in com.google.api.services.positivityapi.Positivityapi.Appreciation
```

I have several questions :

- How to solve my issue?
- Am I including the libraries correctly in my Android project?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I  have tried to include the libraries in Eclipse I still have this compilation error. The Endoinpts are working if i use Javascript API. I am wondering the problem itself is not related to the generated source code. I am not in charge of the GAE and endpoints development I just know it is developed in python. I will try to get more information about what version is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust your build.grade file using this file as an example. This will dynamically pull in the dependencies and prevent you from having to check them in.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-android/blob/master/HelloEndpointsProject/HelloEndpoints/build.gradle

If you continue to have missing dependencies make sure you've downloaded the required packages from the SDK manager as specified in the same project's README file:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-android

Comment: The problem was coming from python code that was respecting some naming convention in his code. So the code generated in java was not correct. It was normal it did not compile. I will try to get more details with the python developer in our team to give more details to people who might encounter the same problem.

Comment: I had issues using a model named `Entry`, I was getting a compiler error: cannot find symbol for a generated class named `MyApiNameEntry` I then changed the name of the class and it worked fine.